# Checking a Selected value in the combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, selectedvalue

hi all  i was trying to check if a certain selected value in a combobox has been selected 
i've been trying something like this :

```
if (Type_CB.SelectedValue == 3)
        {
         ///Do some Code
        }
```

but it doesn't seem to work

so is there is any idea

Comment: Have you tried selectedItem instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the above comments and answers are correct. In your case, I assume you have added manually some number in your comboBox. Therefore the following would solve your problem:

```
string value = Type_CB.SelectedItem.ToString();
string value2 = "3";
if (value2 == value)
{
do some work
}
```

Comment: this one did work out but i changer the `SelectedItem.ToString();` to `SelectedValue.ToString();`

Comment: Very good. Have a look here for hints about how to use a combo box. http://www.dotnetperls.com/combobox

Answer (score 0):

Because what you want to do is use the [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Or you can use `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` if you have the actual item/value, but best thing to use is `SelectedIndex`.